# Mk4 Astra judders, runs hot p0420 p0170 p1130

Tags: electronic-control-module, vauxhall, astra

I have a Mk4 Astra 1.8 petrol 2002 130k Miles. 
When starting the idle speed revs up & down, it judders when driving the first 500metres. Plenty of oil, water was a bit low. During a 2 hour journey the engine got hot (needle in middle) and the orange engine symbol came on. The ECU codes are

```
p0420 
p0170 
p1130
```

The DTC freeze data are:

```
DTC freeze: P0170;
Fuel sys1 = CL
Fuel sys2 N/A
LOADPCT = 12.9%
ETC     = 75deg
SHRTFTI = 8.6%
LONGFTI = 15.6%
RPM = 915/min
VSS = 10km/h
```

In the readiness monitors it says EGR SYS = N/A does N/A mean the EGR has been bypassed/disabled?

Any thoughts what I should start with to fix this engine problem?

Comment: can you confirm what the p1130 code is? and any relevant freeze frame data for the code. I'd suspect you either have a vacuum/exhaust leak or the afr sensor is bad.

Comment: P1130 = Air/Fuel Sensor Circuit Range/Performance (). P0420 Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold (so CAT has failed maybe ude to misfiring, hopefully not an issue until next MOT). P0170 Fuel trim malfunction.

Comment: My cheapy OBD scanner only gives the freeze frame data for the P0170 code, maybe that's the most recent? Thanks for the tips,  I'll try cleaning the air flow sensor with Wynns EGR/AFR cleaner and check for vacuum leaks maybe with the propane trick this evening & see what I find.

Comment: I'd ignore the p0420 code until you resolve the 170 and 1130 code. monitor the afr sensor, induce a vacuum leak and maybe add some external fuel to the system see if the afr sensor responds correctly.